# Node Express MySql Sql query doesn't work

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm very new to Node Express,I tried to learn it by following some tutorials

**Below code segment work fine**
**it shows**

> Express server is running under port no : 3000 DB connection succeded.

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyparser.json());


var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost', 
    user:'root',
    password:'',
    database:'employeedb'
});

mysqlConnection.connect((err)=>{
  if(!err)
  console.log('DB connection succeded.');
  else
  console.log('DB connection failed \n Error : '+ JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));
});

app.listen(3000,()=>console.log('Express server is running under port no : 3000'));
```

**Then I Tried run Below code segment**

```
app.get('/ab',(req,res)=>{
    console.log("test1");
  mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM employee',(err,rows,fields)=>{
     console.log("test2");  
     if (!err){
     console.log(rows);
      res.send(rows);
  }
     else{
     console.log(err);
   }
  })

console.log("test3");

});
```

**Problem is browser take long time to show response and it show**

> localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

**But in terminal only test1 and test3 printed**

according to my knowledge, if an error exists, the error should be displayed. isn't it so? But here, no error is displayed. Please help me get this error fixed

Comment: Did you check that mysql is running or not? check your console and see if DB connection succeded is present or not

Comment: Express server is running under port no : 3000
DB connection succeded. when server starts it shows this.

Comment: Is employee table exist in DB?

Comment: yes.if not it should be displayed as an error isn't it?

Comment: @DanielE. then how can I write it

Comment: try adding `res.status(500).send('Something broke!')` after the `console.log(err)`

Comment: @ChandiPremarathne it should be res.json(rows) but res.send(rows) is also fine

Comment: @JanithKasun problem is there's no any line works inside  mysqlConnection.query....... atleast  console.log("test2");

Comment: Just add mysql query block in try catch and see if any error got in catch?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried when the get request is called then connect the db?

```
app.get('/ab',(req,res)=>{
  mysqlConnection.connect((err)=>{
    if(!err){
      console.log('DB connection succeded.');
      mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM employee',(err,rows,fields)=>{
          console.log("test2");  
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to narrow down the possibilities change the query to...

SELECT * FROM employee LIMIT 1

you’re currently returning all the records in the employee table, which could take a longer than the request timeout. Just return 1 record to start.

Answer (score 0):

There is no **bug/error** in your code. I've tried in my system and getting exact same output. **PFA**.

**All three consoles:**

[image]

**Data that are exist in DB**

[image]

**Code:**

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyparser.json());


var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost', 
    user:'root',
    password:'root',
    database:'employeedb'
});

mysqlConnection.connect((err)=>{
  if(!err)
  console.log('DB connection succeded.');
  else
  console.log('DB connection failed \n Error : '+ JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));
});
app.get('/ab',(req,res)=>{
  console.log("test1");
mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM employee',(err,rows,fields)=>{
   console.log("test2");  
   if (!err){
   console.log(rows);
    res.send(rows);
}
   else{
   console.log(err);
 }
})

console.log("test3");

});


app.listen(3000,()=>console.log('Express server is running under port no : 3000'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just create a new variable for DB and call DB variable for your query.
Then your code snippet look like:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyparser.json());


var mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost', 
    user:'root',
    password:'',
    database:'employeedb'
});

const db = mysqlConnection.connect((err)=>{
  if(!err)
  console.log('DB connection succeded.');
  else
  console.log('DB connection failed \n Error : '+ JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));
});

app.listen(3000,()=>console.log('Express server is running under port no : 3000'));
```

then just call db for your purpose

```
app.get('/ab',(req,res)=>{
    console.log("test1");
  db.query('SELECT * FROM employee',(err,rows,fields)=>{
     console.log("test2");  
     if (!err){
     console.log(rows);
      res.send(rows);
  }
     else{
     console.log(err);
   }
  })

console.log("test3");

});
```

Hope it will worked!